# Check filesize with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a jQuery check that checks if a file-size is larger than an certain amount. If so, then return false. Yes, I also have an check for this in back-end (PHP), but would like to have a front-end solution as well.

Here's a code snippet I'm working on:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkfile() {
        var chkFile = document.getElementById("file").files[0].size;
        if(chkFile < 20000) {
            alert("file size is allowed");
        return true;
        } else {
            alert("file size is not allowed");
        return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Manage to solve my own question.

I succeded to implement the filesize-check in my frontend check for the form.

This is my code:

```
        var chkFile = document.getElementById("file").files[0].size;

        if (!validateFilesize(chkFile)) {
            $('span.error_msg_file').html('File is too large.');
            $("#file").focus();
        return false;
        }

        function validateFilesize(k) {
            if(chkFile >= 20000) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Also reconsider AnchovyLegend's answer as you have now two separate validation checks on back and frontend which is usually bad practice.

Comment: @jazZRo Why is this bad practice?

Comment: It is not recommended to have two separate validations because when they are not giving the same result (e.g. updated the backend but forgot the frontend) you risk bad user experience.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already implemented the backend file size validation with php, submit an ajax request to the backend for front-end validation:

```
function checkfile() {
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: 'file_validation.php', //backend file validation solution, returns boolean
         success: function(fileSize){
            if(fileSize){
                 //Valid
            }else{
               //Too Large
            }
         }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I don't think this will work in my situation. Could you assist me with an example using only frontend check? My file-validation is in the same file. I use if ($_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'] && !$_FILES && !$_POST) {//errormsg } else { //it's ok.. } to check in backend. Thanks.